# Why is the HID_MAX_USAGES value so low in kernel?

Tags: kernel, mouse, games

I was wondering why the `HID_MAX_USAGES` value was still less than 13k, when most gaming mices need 32k or 64k. Values are found in `include/linux/hid.h` from the kernel sources, and this is still affecting kernels up to 3.10.5

Does Canonical have a good reason NOT to use 64.000 as a value for `HID_MAX_USAGES` in their kernels ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I don't have an aswer yet, but *kernel 3.11.0* (stable) works great with gaming mices, altough the `HID_MAX_USAGES` is still on ~13k. So, it's solved, and possessors of gaming mices will no longer need to rebuild the kernel with modified `hid.h`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this question has already been answered on the LKML ([source](https://lkml.org/lkml/2013/5/28/144))

> Date  Tue, 28 May 2013 12:13:45 +0200 (CEST) From Jiri Kosina <>
>   Subject   Re: [PATCH 0/2] Holtek gaming mouse driver, and the necessity
>   for it instead of increasing HID_MAX_USAGES
>
> On Tue, 21 May 2013, Christian Ohm wrote:
>
> > Is there any reason why HID_MAX_USAGES shouldn't be more than 12288?
>
> Well, the reasoning is a mixture of current implementation, and 
>   reasonability.
>
> - we currently have statically allocated arrays on a per-parser basis, for    parsing usages and collection indices. If the number of max
>     usages is    going to grow in an uncontrolled manner, we'll have to
>     change the way    our parser works (which is not impossible, of
>     course).
> - most of the ocurences of huge max usages being presented by the devices    have actually turned out to be bogus and could have been
>     fixed by    patching the report descriptor in order to reflect the
>     real behavior of    the device
>
> Thanks,
>
> --  Jiri Kosina SUSE Labs